# If there is an integer $n$ such that $n^2\equiv3\pmod p$, where $p$ is prime, prove there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $|a^2-3b^2|=p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

> If there is an integer $n$ such that $n^2\equiv3\pmod p$, where $p$ is prime, prove there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $|a^2-3b^2|=p$.

So $n^2-3 = pm$ for some integer $m$, and I know $|a^2 - 3b^2|$ is the norm map of an element in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$, but I'm having difficulty piecing these pieces together.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677748/algorithm-to-find-solutions-p-x-y-for-the-equation-p-x2-ny2/677759#677759

Comment: I should probably add that discriminant 12 has only two classes, $x^2 - 3 y^2$ and $3 x^2 - y^2.$